# Cannot find Chrome binary when running Webdriverio tests in Docker

Tags: javascript, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, webdriver-io

I am struggling trying to run `wdio` test in `Docker`, the error is that it cannot find `Chrome binary` with the current setup

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  code:
    image: my-image
    build:
        dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
        context: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - "selenium"
    command: /bin/bash -c "cd app; npm test"
  selenium:
      image: selenium/standalone-chrome
      volumes:
        - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
      ports:
        - "4444:4444"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10.15.3
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt update && apt install default-jre -y
```

wdio.conf.js

```
...
exports.config = {

    runner: 'local',
    // host: process.env.HOST,
    host: 'selenium',
    port: 4444,
...
```

error after running `docker-compose up`

```sh
code_1      | 0-0 worker error { name: 'unknown error',
code_1      |   message:
code_1      |    'unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600233
```

Comment: I've managed to make it working editing the docker-compose.yml adding:

`network_mode: host`

Comment: You are running the tests on the host machine?

Answer (score 0):

Had to edit the docker-compose.yml as follow:

````
version: "3.7"

services:
  code:
    network_mode: host
    image: my-image
    build:
        dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
        context: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - "selenium"
    command: /bin/bash -c "cd app; npm test"
  selenium:
      network_mode: host
      image: selenium/standalone-chrome:3.141.59-oxygen
      volumes:
        - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    ```
````